# Exclude left join in case of empty cells

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, string

So I need to join the company table only in the case that the email field is populated.

Is there a way to exclude the company table join in case there is an empty email field?

```
select * from person p left join company c on(substring_index(p.email, '@', -1)=c.website and p.email <> '')
```

I can't do it with a "where" clause because I am joining yet another table, and I want that table joined regardless.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! A flash of inspiration, and...

```
select * from person p left join company c on((case when length(p.email)>0 then substring_index(p.email,'@',-1) else "purplepower" end)=c.website)
```

By using the "case" clause I have made sure that only the email values that exist are matched.  If not, it is matching an arbitrary string which of course doesn't match to the company table.

Answer (score 0):

That's overly complicated, and an elaborate workaround that is unnecessary. By nature a `LEFT JOIN` will attempt to join the other table on the column you specify and **if it cannot join it, columns from that table are NULL**. Also, a join is used to return columns from multiple tables based on a joining condition. Since you are using a left join, you will return **all** rows from the *person* table regardless of the email value.

Since you don't select anything from *company* and use a left join, your workaround solution query is the same as:

```
select * from person p 
where p.email <> ''
```

---

Based on your comment that there is another table in the works, you could force *company* to have a value:

```
select * from person p 
left join company c on (
    substring_index(p.email, '@', -1) = c.website
    AND c.website <> '')
```

Comment: Actually, no--what you're missing is that the company table has over 5 million rows and a good 500k of them are blank in the website field. So a left join on an empty cell is creating 500k duplicates.  In addition, there's a third table that needs to be joined to the person table, so the "Where" clause doesn't work since that third table should be joined with or without email.

Comment: Why are you joining to the company table?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select * from person where email <> '') p 
  left join company c 
  on(substring_index(p.email, '@', -1)=c.website )
```